# List with backing property doesn't get a value added in

Tags: c#, list

I thought of a neat way for accessing a list property:

```
private List<int> _stages;
public List<int> Stages
{
    get
    {
        return (_stages ?? (_stages = new List<int>())).OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
    }
    set
    {
        _stages = value;
    }
}
```

This way even if `Stages` is null, if I use `Stages.Add(1)` it would be initialized first and then the value be added. However it does not work and I really cannot figure it out since there is not much to debug. `_stages` gets initialized, but no matter how many times I call `Stages.Add(1)`, `_stages` is still an empty list.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return (_stages ?? (_stages = new List<int>())).OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
```

This is equivalent to this:

```
var stages = _stages;
if (stages == null)
    stages = _stages = new List<int>();

return stages.OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
```

So while you properly initialize the list when it is null, you are still always returning `.OrderBy(s => s).ToList()`.

The [`Enumerable.ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) call will *always* create a new list.

So the list being returned by the getter is a new list, which is not linked to the internally backed `_stages` list. So when you add an item to the list, you are adding it to the sorted copy but not the original list.

You could change this by assigning the sorted list back to the backing field all the time, but this would still introduce the overhead of always sorting the field whenever you access the property. And accessing getters in general should not have side effects, so I would avoid doing that. It’s better to provide maybe a clear `SortStages` method on the object to actually sort the list.

Also, you should consider using [`List.Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) to sort the list in-place, so you don’t end up with new list objects.

Comment: Yes, `List.Sort()` was what I tried achieve but with the wrong tools which led to my mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By doing `ToList()` you are returning a new list. If you call `Add` on it, it won't end up in `_stages`

Comment: I knew I was missing something really small though really important! Thanks!